# Add Page Title to source key in url for use in a form - Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, url, query-string

I am trying to add a waitlist button functionality to a page on my wordpress website. **Basically I need to autopopulate the source key in the query string in a url with the page title.**

More Details:

I have the button linking to a general waitlist form but I want the product information from the page title go into a text field. I can do this by using a source key in the url.

We have our product listed on a portfolio post here with a waitlist button: http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/renohifi/listings_portfolio/pass-labs-xa-160-8-monoblock-power-amps/

The button goes to a form [here](http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/renohifi/waitlist-request/) with a text field that auto populates with the source key in the url.

So if I use the link: http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/renohifi/waitlist-request/?source=Pass%20Labs%20XA-160.8%20Monoblock%20Power%20Amps, The source key will populate the the product text field with "Pass Labs XA-160.8 Monoblock Power Amps". This all works great!

Now, I want to automate the code for the button so it always pulls the Page title as the source key so we don't have to manually enter in code for each button.

**How can I get the page title to auto-populate the query string in the link url so that the link will be http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/renohifi/waitlist-request/?source={PAGE_TITLE}**?

FYI - I am using the Visual Composer plugin for page layout and button creation.

UPDATE:
I am trying to use code like this:

```
<div class="vc_btn3-container vc_btn3-center">
    <a title="Waitlist - <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/renohifi/waitlist-request/?source=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>">
        Add Me to the Waitlist
    </a>
</div>
```

It is in the Wordpress editor so the code is not showing up as anything other than code. I want the title to show (I am trying two different wordpress calls for the page title). You can see this in the 2nd "Add Me to the Wishlist" Button on the first link above.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can get the page title from the DOM using `document.title`, the value is encoded using the [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.

Your URL as a JavaScript string:

```
var url = "http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/renohifi/waitlist-request/?source=" + encodeURIComponent(document.title);
```

I couldn't find any reference to the URL on the page to which you linked.

**EDIT:** To encode the title string using PHP you need to use the [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

Template code:

```
<div class="vc_btn3-container vc_btn3-center">
  <a title="Waitlist - <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/renohifi/waitlist-request/?source=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>">
    Add Me to the Waitlist
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: See code above, it is in the second Add to Waitlist button on the first link above.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding a shortcode instead:

```
function shortcode_waitlist( $atts ){

  $pagetitle =  get_the_title();
  $link = '<div class="vc_btn3-container vc_btn3-center"><a class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-lg vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-block vc_btn3-color-primary" href="http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/renohifi/waitlist-request/?source='.$pagetitle.'" title="Waitlist - '.$pagetitle.'">Add Me to the Waitlist</a></div>';

    return $link;
}

add_shortcode( 'waitlist_button', 'shortcode_waitlist' );
```

Then just used [waitlist_button] in the page.

Thanks for your suggestions, they helped me get to where I needed to go.